# Compilation error after upgrade to gcc 9 when using concepts with argument pack in if constexpr

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, c++-concepts, gcc9

I have a code that uses a concept with argument pack in `if constexpr` context. It used to compile and work in gcc 8 but breaks in gcc 9:

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
concept
#if __GNUC__ < 9
bool
#endif
is_handled = requires(T handler, Ts && ...args) {
    handler.handle(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
};

template <typename T>
concept
#if __GNUC__ < 9
bool
#endif
has_name = requires(T) {
    T::name;
};

template <typename ...Handlers>
struct Dispatcher {

    template <typename ...Ts>
    void operator()(Ts && ...args) {
        std::apply(
            [&](auto && ...handlers) {
                (handle(handlers, std::forward<Ts>(args)...),...); 
            },
            m_handlers
        );
    }

private:
    template <typename Handler, typename ...Ts>
    void handle(Handler & handler, Ts && ...args) {
        if constexpr (is_handled<Handler, Ts...>) {
            handler.handle(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
        }
    }

    template <typename Handler>
    char const* get_code() {
        if constexpr (has_name<Handler>) {
            return Handler::name;
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

    std::tuple<Handlers...> m_handlers;
};
```

The error produced by GCC 9.2 is:

```
<source>: In member function 'void Dispatcher<Handlers>::handle(Handler&, Ts&& ...)':
<source>:38:49: error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token
   38 |         if constexpr (is_handled<Handler, Ts...>) {
      |                                                 ^
```

[See compiler explorer here](https://godbolt.org/z/WjFAMo). You can switch between gcc versions 8.3 and 9.2 to see the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that it should compile and that it is a regression in GCC 9.1.

There is already a bug report for this in GCC's bug tracker [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91073).

You can avoid the parser bug by placing additional parentheses around the `if constexpr` condition, forcing it to be parsed as expression instead of declaration:

```
if constexpr ((is_handled<Handler, Ts...>)) {
    //...
}
```